# Use transition with hover without it reverting to previous state

Tags: html, css, transform

I have a div `'box'` which `rotates 90 degrees` `when the user hovers it`.

When the user moves the mouse away the box counter rotates back to its original position.

**I would like to prevent this. 
I.E: When the user hover over the box it rotates and stays that way, even when he removes the mouse from the box.**

> Please look at for the basic setup:

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 1s all; 
}
.box:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Hover me!
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cdawa5z7/)

What should I change in order to make it act as I want?

Comment: Use JavaScript to change the transform value on hover

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way you can achieve this using `animation`**

Like this

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: 1s all;
  animation: rotate .4s forwards paused;
}
.box:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
    }
  to {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Hover me!
</div>
```

**Or**

You can use `js`. Like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: 1s all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  Hover me!
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!